# Is it possible to render a view with "get parameters"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, get, request

Is it possible to render a view with get parameters ?
For example, something like :

render "/projects/sheets?id=43"

It's because I need to render a view which uses url parameters to work properly.

I tried many ways, but it only creates parameters that I can get only in the controller and that are not available after.

It's because I want to have a view that contains the html code of many other views.

This is my current code :

allProjects.html.erb :

```
<% Project.where(productchief: user.id).order(:title).each do |project| %>
<%= render "/projects/sheets?id=#{project.id}" #This doesn't work. %>
<% end %>
```

It's because I want to have a view that contains the content of all the other views in my website to allow the users to print all this content in one time.

Comment: are you rendering the partial from the controller or from another view? Can't you set the property in the controller as an instance variable?

Comment: It's not a partial, it is a view that I want to render and I wanna render it from another view.
I have a view named allProjects in which I want to have all the html of the views that displayed projects (/projects/sheets?id=x is the route for the view that display a project)
And no I can't set the property in the controller as an instance variable. It will be not consistent with the treatment I have in my views.

Comment: i need more coffee ... could have sworn your question made reference to using partials. Might be worth you adding the extra information from your comment to your original question as it's quite relevant.

Comment: Sorry, I have added some code and explanations ! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do it in the way you are trying to do it. You will need to change /projects/sheets to be a partial and render that instead and pass through local variables.

So to clarify /projects/sheets.html.erb becomes /projects/_sheets.html.erb and you would then invoke as:

```
<%= render partial: "/projects/sheets", locals: { :project_id = project.id } %>
```

Then within the partial _sheets.html.erb you can make reference to project_id

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should be able to access the params in a view but unless there's a very specific reason you can't, I suggested altering your routes. I may be missing some info from your original question, but let's say you have routes as:

```
  get 'projects/sheets', to: "projects#index", as: :projects
  get 'projects/sheets/:id', to: "projects#show", as: :project
```

That would change your urls a little but would still leave the params available. Using the routes above, for example and going to: `localhost:3000/projects/sheets/5?something_fun=geeks_are_us` will give the following params:

```
{"something_fun"=>"geeks_are_us", "controller"=>"projects", "action"=>"show", "id"=>"5"}
```

And if you're looking to render multiple items via a partial, you can pass the assigned variable for (in your case) 'project' to render the views but it *is* a partial as you appear to be rendering from a view already.

So something like:

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <%= render partial: project, locals: {project: project} %>
<% end %>
```

This would try to render projects/_project.html.erb and sending project as a variable. If you need other variables in your view, just pass them in the locals hash.

Hope this is some help.